# How to remove small horizontal line at the end of a loop with with noEnd=True in algpseudocodex

Tags: environments, algpseudocode

I'm using the algpseudocodex package with the option noEnd=True since I don't like the EndFor/EndWhile, etc, at the end of each loop.

The problem is that I would like to remove the small horizontal line that is used at the end of each loop:
[image]

I am not a LaTeX expert and was trying to read the definitions inside the [package](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/algpseudocodex/algpseudocodex.sty). It looks like the \algpx@indXLineLength is used to control the length of the horizontal line. I was trying to change it from my main tex file after importing the package, but I wasn't able to.
Is there a way to do it or an alternative approach?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.